# how to recover the Database Data using binary logs?

Tags: mysql, database, binary-log

One of our associate has deleted the database as well as the replica is there is a way to recover the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not without a backup. Binary logs are only used to recover from the last backup up to a certain point in time. They can not be used to roll back some statements.